# $\varepsilon$-chain property for the inverse function

Tags: general-topology, analysis, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to solve a problem of Lan Wen's differentiable Dynamical Systems book.

Before writing the problem I introduce some notions in here:

Denote by $X$ a compact metric space and by $f:X \to X$ a homeomorphism.

By an $\varepsilon$-chain we mean a sequence $x_0 , \cdots , x_n$ which satisfy $d(f(x_i),x_{i+1}) < \varepsilon$ for $ 0 \leq i \leq n-1$

Here is the problem:

> Prove that for any $\delta >0 $ there is $ \eta>0$ such that if $ x_0 ,\cdots , x_k$ is an $\eta$-chain of $f$, then $x_k , \cdots, x_0$ is a $\delta$-chain of $f^{-1}$.

My try : I believe that here we could use the fact that $ f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$ and we could consider $0<\eta<\delta$ and for any $x,y \in X$ if $d(x,y) < \eta$ then $d(f(x) , f(y))<\varepsilon$. considering this if we suppose $x_0 , \cdots , x_k$ is an $\eta$-chain then we need to prove $x_k, \cdots , x_0$ is a $\delta$-chain under $f^{-1}$. Is this idea a true way to solve this problem or I need to think differently?

Comment: You also are given that $f^{-1}$ is a function and continuous, with all the stated consequences.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes thank you. a good point that I ignored. problem solved. thanks.

Comment: @Amathsfreak Then you should write an official answer to your own question to clear it from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @PaulFrost I added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(x_0, \cdots , x_k)$ is an $\eta$-chain under $f$ so $d(f(x_i),x_{i+1}) < \eta$ for $0 \leq i \leq k-1$. I claim that $(x_k , \cdots , x_0)$ is a $\delta$-chain under $f^{-1}$. I need to prove $d(f^{-1}(x_k), x_{k-1}) < \delta ,\cdots, d(f^{-1}(x_1),x_0)< \delta $.

Since $X$ is compact and $f$ is a homeomorphism so $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is uniformly continuous so I can say that there exists $\eta>0$ such that if $d(x,y)<\eta$ then $d(f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(y))<\delta$. (here $\eta$ is the one we have in the question).
Now since $d(f(x_i),x_{i+1})<\eta$ so $d(f^{-1}(f(x_{i}),f^{-1}(x_{i+1}))<\delta$ so
\begin{align}
d(x_i,f^{-1}(x_{i+1}))<\delta \quad , 0 \leq i\leq k-1
\end{align}

This is what I wanted to prove.

Comment: You can also accept your answer.

Comment: I'll do it as soon as the website let me .